# Can you save an array of GeoPoints using Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, geopoints

I would like to store geoPoints in an array and I know parse has a datatype of geoPoint. Is it possible to create an array of just those geoPoints? Thanks. 
FYI: This is an iOS app but it really shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I'd create the array column on your dashboard, then inside your iOS app you use `[ (yourPfObject) addObject:(objectYoureAdding) forKey:(keyOfArray) ];` and objects can be of any type.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure if you could do it or if you would have to store a column for both lat and long coordinates.

Comment: No problem! 

If I recall correctly, the objectForKey of an array is a NSArray, which is immutable. So if you ever try to get and modify the whole array, keep that in mind. You have to create a mutable array using [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: ] or something similar.  Just a tip while moving forward!